# Google Analytics API: entrances same as exits in query

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I am experiencing some strange issue with the Google Analytics API and PHP.
When I retrieve the entrances along with the exits, I get the same counts for both:

```
  $optParams = array();
  $metrics    = 'ga:entrances,ga:exits,ga:entranceRate,ga:pageViews';
  $start_date = $hidden_from;
  $end_date   = $hidden_to;
  $optParams['dimensions']  = 'ga:date';
  $optParams['sort']        = '-ga:date';
  $result = $analytics->data_ga->get( $analytics_id,
            $start_date,
            $end_date, $metrics, $optParams);
```

When I remove one of them (ga:entrances, or ga:exits) I get different numbers. Also, using the GA query explorer I get correctly the expected result.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something, or is it some sort of a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad me! It makes sense that when you count just the exits and the entrances per one day, these figures will be the same (all visitors have left the site).
It makes sense counting them per page.

Sorry for wasting your time!